# База данных Django

Tags: python, база-данных, django

Как увидеть содержимое базы данных (не через админку), созданной самим Django?

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Нужно вносить изменения самостоятельно, не через модели (парсить данные с сайта в базу). Как это реализовать? Сами данные вытащить могу, однако не знаю, как правильно было бы их записать, куда засунуть скрипт, который это делает.

Comment: В случае с sqlite можно использовать dbrowser (точно есть на linux), там же и все можно внести\вынести и прочее. А вообще в питоне есть модуль для sqlite3, вроде бы так и называется, можно его использовать

Comment: Что мешает парсить данные с сайта в модель?

Comment: @andreymal Как парсить в модель, подскажи?

Comment: Создать management-команду, в которую поместить парсер и в которой можно будет создавать модели как обычно принято в Django `obj = Model(чтототам=чтототам); obj.save()`

Comment: SQLite Studio вам поможет